# Table html/CSS output error: unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I am new to web dev, PHP, CSS and html. I want to put a CSS in my table displaying the data on my database, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

My CSS file is named "table.css" ...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WEW</title>
<head>
<link href="table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>


<?php


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc123","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database_ME", $con);



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM id");

$data->set_css_class("table");

echo "<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>password</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: publish your css also question is not complete

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php about strings and quotes.

Comment: you need to escape quotes echo "<table class=\"table\"> etc ..

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the CSS file is well written, and that it uses the `.table` selector.

There's several syntax errors in there, all because you need to escape the inner `"` like so:

```
echo "A 'string with several \"nesting\" levels' needs escaping.";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table class="table">
```

change to

```
echo "<table class='table'>
```

AND

```
echo "<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">";
```

change to

```
echo "<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';\">";
```

Comment: it works perfectly, tnx for the help!
i want the row to also change when i click on it then it stays on that color as i go to other column. is this possible?this is my css file:

table.hovertable{font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#333333;border-width: 1px;border-color: #999999;border-collapse: collapse; }
table.hovertable th {background-color:#F0E68C;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #a9c6c9; }
table.hovertable tr {background-color:#d4e3e5; }
table.hovertable td {border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #a9c6c9; }

Comment: @jack, 
you couldn't ask the question in comment because it will not shown if somebody search for the same cases.

you can accept or upvote some answer here 
then make a new question by click 'Ask Question' button on right top of this page, so you can get many answer from others and also the others can learn from your question.